# Errors D: I have tried much gone from bad elif to parse errors to this now. Fix?

Tags: bash, shell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If statement is not following its conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13301377/if-statement-is-not-following-its-conditional)

I believe it to be something that be wrong with my bc or my variables, but I could be wrong.

This is a bit of my code.

```
#!/bin/bash
#this is a game that is two player and it is a race to get to 
#100 before the other player

echo "Player 1 name?"

read p1

echo "Player 2 name?"

read p2

echo "Okay $p1 and $p2. $p1 will go first"

p1s=0
p2s=0
pt=1

while [ $pt -eq 1 ]; do

    echo "roll or stay"
    read choice

if [ $choice ="r" ]; then

    die=$(($RANDOM%6+1))
if [ $choice ="s" ]; then

    echo "Okay $p1 your score is $p1s"
    echo "$p2 turn now"
    sleep 1
    count=0
    pt=2

else

    pt=1

    fi
fi

if [ $die -eq 1 ]; then

    p1s=$(echo "$p1s-$count" |bc)
    echo "You rolled a 1. Your score is $p1s"
    echo "$p2 turn now."
    sleep 1
    count=0
    pt=2

elif [ $die -gt 1 ]; then

    p1s=$(echo "$p1s+$die" |bc)
    count=$(echo "$count+$die" |bc)
    echo "You rolled a $die. Your score is $p1s"
    pt=1

fi


if [ $p1s -gt 99 ]; then

    echo "$p1 won. $p2 lost"
    echo "would you like to play again?"
    read again

else

if [ $again ="yes" ]; then

    echo "Okay one second."
    sleep 1
    clear
    bash num.sh

else

if [ $again = "no" ]; then

    exit
else

    echo "I guess no then?"
    exit
        fi
    fi
fi
done
```

What happens is this

Player 1 name?

1

Player 2 name?

2

Okay 1 and 2. 1 will go first

roll or stay

r

num.sh: line 24: [: r: unary operator expected

num.sh: line 42: [: -eq: unary operator expected

num.sh: line 51: [: -gt: unary operator expected

Okay one second.

Player 1 name?

Here it finds bunch of errors and such. Then starts over.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you'll be able to "see" where the errors are if you turn on the shell trace feature, use either `set +x` or `set -vx`. If you want to trace just a small part, then turn it off with `set +vx`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess conditional to check **choice** variable has wrong syntax, it should be written as:

```
if [ "$choice" -eq "r" ]; then
...
```

or with enhanced brackets

```
if [[ "$choice" == "r" ]]; then
...
```